# How do I save all user answers from different users at the same time?

Tags: codeigniter

I am making an online examination in codeigniter and I want to save all the users answers. How do i implement this? Do i need to make mysqli tables for each user?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As written your question is very vague. Please see [ask] and refine your question.

Comment: Im sorry im just new here but to clarify my question,  I would just like to know how to implement networking using codeigniter.

Comment: Yes, you need to use everything in CI. You need to create Controller, Model, View, prepare JS for sending answers into CI, which will check and save them into Database (Postgres, Oracle, phpMyAdmin etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be very new in development. Study the basics on how framework works.

You need not not to make a table for each user . You should have the mysql db design something like below.

[image]